# Question on congruence modulo m and partitions

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

I do not really understand what to do with the following problem and would appreciate any help.

> Let $\Bbb{Z}=\{[0]_6,[1]_6,[2]_6,[3]_6,[4]_6,[5]_6\}. $Consider the purported
>   function $f:\Bbb{Z}_6\rightarrow\Bbb{Z}$ defined by $f([a]_6)=a$ for all
>   $[a]_6\in \Bbb{Z}_6$. Show that $f$ is not well defined.

**Attempt:**

Suppose for contradiction that the putative function $f$ is well defined and therefore single-valued.

By previously established lemma :

> Let $m \gt 1$ be an integer.For all $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ the following
>   holds:
>
> 1.) $[a]_m = [b]_m $ iff $a \equiv b \pmod m$
>
> 2.) $a \in [b]_m$ iff $a \equiv b \pmod m$

Since $0 \equiv 6 \pmod 6$ then by lemma (1),  $[0
]_6=[6]_6$. Applying the function on both sides yields $0=6$ which is a contradiction.

I am unsure because I thought $a$ and $b$ must be restricted to lie between $0$ and $5$ given the defintion of $\Bbb{Z}=\{[0]_6,[1]_6,[2]_6,[3]_6,[4]_6,[5]_6\}$

Comment: You’re right and your prove is perfect

Comment: oh,great..thank you